# Print Linkedlist with 2 integers per node

Tags: java, printing, linked-list

I wanted to create a LinkedList with 2 integers(2 ints per node), so i did this:

```
static class Ocurrencia {

   int renglon, columna;

   public Ocurrencia(int renglon, int columna) {
          this.renglon = renglon;
          this.columna = columna;
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Ocurrencia> prueba = new LinkedList();
        Ocurrencia prue = new Ocurrencia(2, 3);
        prueba.add(prue);

}
```

How can i print the Linkedlist like this? output : [2,3]

Comment: if any of this answers helped you, it would be nice to accept the one that help you. just select the check icon (it becomes green)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override toString method of Object class. Here is correct code

```
class Ocurrencia {

    int renglon, columna;

    public Ocurrencia(int renglon, int columna) {
        this.renglon = renglon;
        this.columna = columna;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "[" + renglon + "," + columna + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Ocurrencia> prueba = new LinkedList();
        Ocurrencia prue = new Ocurrencia(2, 3);
        prueba.add(prue);

        for (Ocurrencia ocurrencia : prueba) {
            System.out.println(ocurrencia);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList<Ocurrencia> prueba = new LinkedList();
Iterator itr = prueba .iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    Ocurrencia prue = (Ocurrencia)itr.next();
    System.out.println("["+prue.renglon+","+prue.columna +"]")
}
```